# Ignore an Entity fields for a Spring REST call

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two Entity classes "`Teacher` & `Class`" where there is a `@OneToMany` relationship between them. The first one has a rest interface at `/teachers/{id}` and the second one has a rest interface at `/classes/{id}`. When a user sends a `GET` request to the `Teacher` interface, he should receive all of the `Teacher` and `Class` fields. But, when the user sends a `GET` request to the `Class` interface, I would like him to receive all of the `Class` fields and only a part of the `Teacher` fields "`firstName`, `lastName`"

Here are the entities code:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Th")
public class Teacher{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String phone;
@Column(unique = true)
@Email
private String email;
private String password;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Class> classes;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Note> notes;

protected Teacher() {

   }
}



@Entity
public class Class {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;
private String name;
@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "subject_id")
private Subject subject;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Grade grade;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id")
private Teacher teacher;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "class_student", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private List<Student> students;

protected Class() {

   }
}
//getters and setters
```

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: If you're using Hibernate criteria's, use Projections to fetch only the required columns..

Answer (score 0):

Your request sounds mutualy exclusive, don't load Teacher object but do load it for it's ID.

You are better off then making the teacher object lazy load and then initialise it once class is loaded.

FYI
@JsonIgnore prevents loading of objects when RESTfull calls are made.